# Overloaded method match for ListItem, invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors, listitem

I know there's a bunch of questions similar to this, but I've looked through them all and I'm still struggling. The problem with this code is in this function

```
private void DisplayCart()
{
    lstCart.Items.Clear();
    CartItem CartItem = default(CartItem);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry CartEntry in CartA) {
        CartItem = (CartItem)CartEntry.Value;
        lstCart.Items.Add(CartItem.Display);
    }
}
```

and the error messages I receive are

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Is this a simple problem of string conversion? I thought I was understanding this up till now though this is throwing me off.

Comment: PS both error messages refer to the line lstCart.Items.Add(CartItem.Display);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parentheses, trying to pass a reference to a method instead of actually calling that method. You just need to do this:

```
lstCart.Items.Add(CartItem.Display());
```

Note that it's `Display()` instead of `Display`.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable guess, but we never see the definition of the `CartItem` object so we don't know for sure that Display is a function as opposed to a property. Again, really good guess!

Comment: @RobEpstein: The second error is "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'", which wouldn't apply if `Display` is a property, would it?